# Will being altered by Tuldaric drive me mad?

Tags: geneforge-2

From what I understand, if you use enough canisters (I think around 7) in Geneforge 2, you'll end up with a different ending because you end up driven a little bit mad.

So far, I've used 0 canisters, and don't plan to use any. However, I joined the Awakened and have the option of being altered by Tuldaric so that I can use the highest level spells.

Will the act of being altered (but still not using any canisters) have the same effect as if I just go ahead and use all the canisters in the game? Just trying to figure out if there's any point in getting altered but then ignoring the canisters.

Comment: I created the [tag:geneforge-2] tag for you. I also removed the [tag:role-playing-tag] from your question since we do not use genre tags on questions unless it is relevant to the question itself.

Comment: [link to a meta about the genre tag rule](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/837/8350) if you are interested

Comment: Thanks. Since I couldn't create the Geneforge-2 tag but needed at least one, I wasn't sure what else to put on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this forum thread](http://pied-piper.ermarian.net/topic/21/664) which claims to have a full listing of all the Geneforge 2 endings, and there's no reference to Tuldaric's modifications having any impact.  Nothing about altering appears anywhere in any reference to an ending as far as I can tell.

Without playing the game through twice, I can't give a definitive answer, but from what I've seen, I think you'll get the "non canister" ending if you don't use canisters but agree to the alteration.

Comment: I've now finished the game, and can confirm that it had no effect.